# write to a excel file

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
public class ExcelLibrary{

/**
 * @param args
 */ 
//method which accepts a sheet name, row number and cell number
// and returns the string value present in that cell
public String getExcelData(String sheetName,int rowNum, int cellNum){
    String retVal=null;
    try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\seleniumbsw9\\data.xlsx"); 
        //get the workbook object
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        //get the sheet [a particular sheet in the workbook]
        Sheet s = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        //get the row [a particular row in the sheet]
        Row r = s.getRow(rowNum);
        //get the cell [a particular cell of the row obtained above]
        Cell c = r.getCell(cellNum);
        //get the string cell value from the cell
        retVal = c.getStringCellValue();            
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retVal;
}
public int getRowCount(String sheetName){
    int lastRow=0;
    try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\seleniumbsw9\\data.xlsx");
        //get the workbook object
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        //get the sheet [a particular sheet in the workbook]
        Sheet s = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        //return the last row in which data is present counted form 0
        lastRow = s.getLastRowNum();        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lastRow;
}
public void writeDataToExcel(String sheetName, int rowNum, int cellNum, String data){
    try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\seleniumbsw9\\data.xlsx");
        //get the workbook object
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        //get the sheet [a particular sheet in the workbook]
        Sheet s = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        //get the row where data needs to be written. This step 
        //assumes that we are writing to a cell in an existing row
        Row r = s.getRow(rowNum);           
        //Create the cell in that row. If we are trying to write to
        //a cell which has not been created, it will throw error. First
        //we need to create a cell, then set the value of the cell
        //This step is not needed if we are writing to an existing cell
        Cell c = r.createCell(cellNum);         
        c.setCellValue(data);
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("D:\\seleniumbsw9\\data.xlsx");
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Please, specify what you want to do and format the question properly. It's impossible to read your question! It's not even a question!

Comment: Adding on to the comment is there a specific reason to use jxl? Because this API has many limitations better to go with apache poi api.

Answer (score -1):

To get Used Rows in Excel file Using Jxl.....

```
package Testpackage;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class Rowcount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException {
        FileInputStream exo=new FileInputStream("E:\\test1.xls");
        Workbook wbo=Workbook.getWorkbook(exo);
        Sheet wso=wbo.getSheet(0);
        int lastrownum;
        lastrownum= wso.getRows();
        System.out.println(lastrownum);
    }
}
```